# How to terminate workflow in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Currently am facing this error after my custom workflow task is completed in Sharepoint 2010. It shows the error 'error occurred', I suspect that the workflow is not terminated properly. How to programmatically terminate the work flow? I saw most of the sites ask us to use the following codes below, but I do not know how to implement the codes.

```
SPWorkflowCollection 
itemWorkflowCollection= listItem.Workflows;
foreach (SPWorkflow itemWorkflow in itemWorkflowCollection)
{
  //cycle workflows associated to the item (listItem)
  if (!itemWorkflow.IsCompleted && itemWorkflow.InternalState == SPWorkflowState.Running)
  {
    foreach (SPWorkflowTask taskWorkflow in itemWorkflow.Tasks)
    {
      //cycle throught all tasks associated to the workflow
      //if task is not completed
      if (taskWorkflow["PercentComplete"].ToString() != “1″)
      {
        //you can cancel or change the running tasks before canceling the workflow
        taskWorkflow["Status"] = “Canceled”;
        taskWorkflow["PercentComplete"] = 1;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        taskWorkflow.Update();
      }
    }
    SPWorkflowManager.CancelWorkflow(itemWorkflow);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you display cancels a workflow which is **not completed** and its **internal state** is **running**. If this is the case all related workflow tasks are cancelled and ultimately the workflow is cancelled.
If you execute this code on your workflow (WF) which has the status "Error occurred" **nothing will happen**.

"Error occurred" means that the WF had an error was **was cancelled** by SharePoint - no need to try to terminate that WF as it is already terminated.

What you need to do now is to find out why this WF threw an error. First check the workflow status page (any error description there like "E-Mail could not be sent"?) then you could check the windows event log for errors (likely there are no related errors) and finally and most importantly you **will** find the error description and further information in your ULS logs.

Comment: You did not specify the error Dwayne. You only said "error occured" - you need to check standard sharepoint sources for errors as I said before.